# post status message on Facebook without opening Facebook wall status page

Tags: android, facebook, post

I am trying to post some predefined message and images on Facebook wall from my Android Application.

**What i did**

I create hash key using openssl and put in to my `Facebook developer app(Native Android App)` also set package name and activity name.  then i use Facebook app key in my application.
I done with all coding and run my application it ask me for login, then i enter username and password but when i click on post message button it showing me `Facebook` status page where i need enter status manually which i don't want. I want to post predefined message on directly wall without opening this page.

Here is my code for your reference.

```
 private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            GetSet gs = new GetSet();               
            postParams.putString("name", gs.getFacebook_menu_name());
            postParams.putString("caption", gs.getFacebook_hotel_name());
            postParams.putString("description", "My rating for this menu is "+gs.getFacebook_menu_rating());
            //postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams.putString("picture", gs.getFacebook_url_address());


            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG",
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this
                                .getApplicationContext(),error.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this
                                    .getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Details suuccesfully post on your wall",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();

        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

Here is two condition.
**a**. If my mobile don't have Facebook Application then it's work fine. It post message on Facebook wall without entering manually

**b**. But if i have Facebook app install in my mobile then it's opening Status page where i have enter message manually which i don't want.

I don't understand what have to do. Because i read somewhere Facebook not allow posting message without opening status page.

Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: You cannot provide a predefined message via the share dialog. You also should not (and I only use should instead of can here because there's no programmatic way of preventing you) provide a predefined message via graph API, you need to provide the end-user with a mechanism to type in a message, and pass it to the graph API. Using predefined messages is against policy. See section IV, #2 of the Facebook Platform Policies - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 0):

This class helps me for sent messages on my Facebook wall WITHOUT dialog:

```
public class FBManager{

private static final String FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = "fb_access_token";
private static final String FB_EXPIRES = "fb_expires";

private Activity context;
private Facebook facebookApi;

private Runnable successRunnable=new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
};    

public FBManager(Activity context){

this.context = context;

facebookApi = new Facebook(FB_API_ID);

facebookApi.setAccessToken(restoreAccessToken());

} 

public void postOnWall(final String text, final String link){
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", text);
            if(link!=null){
                parameters.putString("link", link);
            }
            String response = facebookApi.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            if(!response.equals("")){
                if(!response.contains("error")){
                    context.runOnUiThread(successRunnable);                     
                }else{
                    Log.e("Facebook error:", response);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();     
}


public void save(String access_token, long expires){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor=prefs.edit();
editor.putString(FB_ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token);
editor.putLong(FB_EXPIRES, expires);
editor.commit();
}

public String restoreAccessToken(){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
return prefs.getString(FB_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);      
}

public long restoreExpires(){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
return prefs.getLong(FB_EXPIRES, 0);        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use single sign on for facebook login -  SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK;